# Getting json array value in datatable

Tags: jquery, json, datatable

I have json as shown below

```
{
    "aaData": [
        [
            {
                "displayValue": "Home Page",
                "link": "http://somelink.com"
            },
            "London",
            "1983"
        ],
        [
            {
                "displayValue": "Backlog",
                "link": "http://BacklogApp.com"
            },
            "Paris",
            "1999"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Now in js, i am populating table using sAjaxSource. But I want first column to be a link. I am using fnRowCallback attribute to get data. Here I am checking if first element of the row is not a string (means is an array), then make first element as a link as I have done below

```
"fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull ) {
                if(typeof aData[0] != 'string'){
                    $('td:eq(0)', nRow).html( '<a href="' + aData[0][1] +'" >'  +
                            aData[0][0] + '</a>');
                }
            }
```

But problem is I am not able to get aData[0][0] or aData[0][1] value as it shows undefined.

Does anyone know how can i get "displayValue" and "link" values here????

Comment: i got answer here in someone comment, but just that comment has been deleted. I dont know why.. :(
Answer was to access the values as aData[0]['displayValue']

Answer (score 3):

This is if you are working with object that contains whole JSON. what you need depends on your `aData` content

```
var data = {
   "aaData": [
        [
             {  
                "displayValue":"Home Page",
                "link":"http://somelink.com"
         },
            "London",
            "1983"
        ],
        [
            {   
                "displayValue":"Backlog",
                "link":"http://BacklogApp.com"
         },
            "Paris",
            "1999"
        ]
    ]
}
```

than to access display value of the first displayValue:

```
data.aaData[0][0].displayValue
data.aaData[0][0].link
```

Answer (score 0):

i got answer here in someone comment, but just that comment has been deleted. I dont know why.. :( Answer was to access the values as aData[0]['displayValue']